# VBA to find a column number with match function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the column on a worksheet based on a value on another worksheet. The codes I am using only gets me value of 0 instead of 20 (it's column T on the worksheet). Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my codes and how to make it work? Much appreciated.

```
Sub Month1()

Dim ColNum As Integer

ColNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Std").Range("F2").Value, Sheets("SAN-68855").Row(3), 0)
```

Comment: Use `.Rows(3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the my testing and the output, perhaps your issue is different case?

Origninal data:

[image]

```
Sub colNum()

Dim rowNum As Long

rowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.match("c", Sheet1.Rows(1), 0)
Debug.Print rowNum   'return 3

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application` is not necessary. Try without it.

Comment: Ya, without applicaton it work, probably his issue is how he managing his data

Comment: After fixing the rows, change it to "dim as long" instead of interger, and remove ".value". it's working now

Comment: Here is one reference you can check regarding long vs integer variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long#:~:text=Traditionally%2C%20VBA%20programmers%20have%20used,re%20declared%20as%20type%20Integer.&text=So%2C%20in%20summary%2C%20there's%20almost,an%20Integer%20type%20these%20days. In summary, declared integer and VBA will auto convert it to long type, therefore long is default type for me in most case

Answer (score 0):

### Match in VBA

- The main mistake is `.Row(3)` which has to be `.Rows(3)`.
- Note that if the value is not found, `WorksheetFunction.Match` will raise an error which you have to account for (2nd procedure). Therefore `Application.Match` is preferred (3rd and 4th procedure).
- When using `Application.Match` the result will be either a whole number or an error value. Therefore you have to declare the variable as `Variant` so it can hold both data types.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Month1QF()
    ' A Quick Fix

    Dim ColNum As Long
    ColNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Std").Range("F2").Value, Sheets("SAN-68855").Rows(3), 0)
    MsgBox ColNum

End Sub

Sub Month1WM()
    ' WorksheetFunction.Match
    
    Dim ColNum As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ColNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Std").Range("F2").Value, Sheets("SAN-68855").Rows(3), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ColNum = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The value could not be found.", vbCritical, "Get Column Number"
    Else
        MsgBox "The column number is '" & ColNum & "'.", vbInformation, "Get Column Number"
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub Month1AM()
    ' Application.Match: IsError
    
    Dim ColNum As Variant
    
    ColNum = Application.Match(Sheets("Std").Range("F2").Value, Sheets("SAN-68855").Rows(3), 0)
    If IsError(ColNum) Then
        MsgBox "The value could not be found.", vbCritical, "Get Column Number"
    Else
        MsgBox "The column number is '" & ColNum & "'.", vbInformation, "Get Column Number"
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub Month1AM2()
    ' Application.Match: IsNumeric
    
    Dim ColNum As Variant
    
    ColNum = Application.Match(Sheets("Std").Range("F2").Value, Sheets("SAN-68855").Rows(3), 0)
    If IsNumeric(ColNum) Then
        MsgBox "The column number is '" & ColNum & "'.", vbInformation, "Get Column Number"
    Else
        MsgBox "The value could not be found.", vbCritical, "Get Column Number"
    End If
    
End Sub
```